# Thymeleaf - Add leading zero to date field if day or month is entered as D/M instead of DD/MM

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I have this code for date entry in a Thymeleaf template:

```
<div class="m-form-row__content">
    <ul class="m-textbox-group" data-module="a-autojump">
        <li class="m-textbox-group__item"><label
            class="m-textbox-group__item-label" for="pHolder.dobDay">Day</label>

            <input type="text" id="pHolder.dobDay"
            th:field="*{pHolder.dobDay}" placeholder="DD"
            class="a-textbox a-textbox--2-character" maxlength="2" /></li>
        <li class="m-textbox-group__item"><label
            class="m-textbox-group__item-label" for="pHolder.dobMonth">Month</label>

            <input type="text" id="pHolder.dobMonth"
            th:field="*{pHolder.dobMonth}" placeholder="MM"
            class="a-textbox a-textbox--2-character" maxlength="2" /></li>
        <li class="m-textbox-group__item"><label
            class="m-textbox-group__item-label" for="pHolder.dobYear">Year</label>

            <input type="text" id="pHolder.dobYear"
            th:field="*{pHolder.dobYear}" placeholder="YYYY"
            class="a-textbox a-textbox--4-character" maxlength="4" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The date format should be DD/MM/YYYY but currently if something like D/M/YYYY is entered no validation catches this and it causes an error in a downstream application. I'd like to add some functionality where a leading zero is added if the length of D or M are 1.

An example of what I'm trying to do but done with JSP and JavaScript are as follows:

```
<div class="input">
    <div class="textfield inputGroup">
    <form:input path="proposer.dobDay" id="proposer.dobDay"
    cssClass="input-text small dayfield only-digits validateFrontend" size="3" maxlength="2"
    onkeyup="moveOnMaxDob(this,'proposer.dobMonth')" onchange="joinDOBVal()" />
    <form:input path="proposer.dobMonth" id="proposer.dobMonth"
    cssClass="input-text small monthfield only-digits validateFrontend" size="3" maxlength="2"
    onkeyup="moveOnMaxDob(this,'proposer.dobYear')" onchange="joinDOBVal()"/>
    <form:input path="proposer.dobYear" id="proposer.dobYear"
    cssClass="input-text small yearfield only-digits validateFrontend" size="5" maxlength="4"
    onchange="joinDOBVal()"/>
    <span class="validIcon"></span>
    <div class="errorContainerContact"></div>
    <!-- hidden fields for full dob -->
    <form:hidden path="proposer.dob" id="proposer.dob"/>
    </div>
    <div class="errorContainer dob">
        <form:errors path="proposer.dob" cssClass="field-validation-error" htmlEscape="false" />
   </div>
</div>
```

```
function joinDOBVal() {
    var day = document.getElementById("proposer.dobDay").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("proposer.dobMonth").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("proposer.dobMonth").value;
    if (IsNumeric(day) == true && IsNumeric(month) == true
            && IsNumeric(year) == true) {

        if(day != "" && day.length == 1 && day != "0") {
            day = "0"+day;
            document.getElementById("proposer.dobDay").value = day;
        }
        if(month != "" && month.length == 1 && month != "0") {
            month = "0"+month;
            document.getElementById("proposer.dobMonth").value = month;
        }
        if ((year != "") && (year.length == 4)) {
            var fullDob = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            document.getElementById("proposer.dob").value = fullDob;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("proposer.dob").value = "";
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("proposer.dob").value = "";
    }
}
```

Think maybe I could do something along the lines of but not quite this:

```
<input th:if="${policyHolder.dobDay.count} &gt; 1" type="text" id="pHolder.dobDay"
            th:field="*{pHolder.dobDay}" placeholder="DD"
            class="a-textbox a-textbox--2-character" maxlength="2" />
<input th:if="${policyHolder.dobDay.count} &eq; 1" type="text" id="pHolder.dobDay"
            th:field="0*{pHolder.dobDay}" placeholder="DD"
            class="a-textbox a-textbox--2-character" maxlength="2" />
```

**Update**

My understanding is that the `label` passes the value to `input` e.g. `for="policyHolder.dobDay"` and `id="policyHolder.dobDay"`. Is it possible to do some sort of `th:if` in the `label` so the desired value is passed to be input?

Comment: have you considered to use any calendar library?

Comment: Sorry, just realised not everything I had in my question was posted. A calendar library would prob be the best option but I'm just trying to do what's been requested of me.